# dynamically allocating space for variable in ksh

Tags: unix, shell-script, ksh

I am new to ksh unix shell scripting.I need my ksh script to get inputs from the user. and the  number of inputs is unkown. I need to get the inputs and process again further .The sample run could be :

**Enter the input values :**
*Hello 
how 
are 
you*

**Select two values from the above :**
*how 
you*

Here the italized text are the inputs from the user.The inputs number given by the user is unknown .I down know how to handle the values given by user. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use [read](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/classes/ksh/stdio.html) to store the values:

```
read values?"Enter the input values: ";
```

Then use [set](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/classes/ksh/arguments.html) to generate positional parameters:

```
set -- $values
```

Finally, print the fields matching the specified positions:

```
echo $1 $3
```

Given "Hello how are you", the output is "Hello are".